# Buttons generated in JavaScript aren't showing up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, object

I'm trying to add a search filter to sort my HTML elements by "data-" tag but some of the buttons I'm trying to generate from the JavaScript do not show up at all.

```
$(function() {
    var $imgs = $("#people img");
    var $buttons = $("#buttons");
    var qualities = {};

    $imgs.each(function() {
        var properties = $(this).data("qualities");

        if (properties) {
            properties.split(",").forEach(function(quality) {
                if (qualities[quality] == null) {
                    qualities[quality] = [];
                }
                qualities[quality].push(p);
            });
        }
    });

    $("<button/>", {
        text: "All",
        class: "on",
        click: function() {
            $(this).addClass("on").siblings().removeClass("on");
            $imgs.show();
        }
    }).appendTo($buttons);

    $.each(qualities, function(quality) {
        $("<button/>", {
            text: quality + " (" + qualities[quality].length + ")",
            click: function() {
                $(this).addClass("on").siblings().removeClass("on");
                $imgs.hide().filter(qualities[quality]).show();
            }
        }).appendTo($buttons);
    });

});
```

Here is a JSFiddle for it: https://jsfiddle.net/1pxp3j9t/

I'm not sure why one of the buttons shows up but the others do not.

Comment: You are declaring your array incorrectly.  Needs to use [ ], not {}.

It is not loading the other buttons because "qualities" is undefined, so it never makes it into your each loop.

var qualities = {}; should be var qualities = [];

Comment: @Mathyou According to your html, there are no images to loop through, thus no buttons get created because your qualities object is empty.

Comment: Please include all relevant HTML, CSS, and JavaScript **in the question itself, here on Stack Overflow.** Do not just link to it. If that site is blocked by someone's corporate firewall, or just goes down, this question will make less sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var $imgs = $("#people img");
```

Nothing happens here because your elements in `div#people` aren't `img`, they're `p`.

```
qualities[quality].push(p);
```

After fixing that, this doesn't work -- you meant to pass the element as `p` to this anonymous function.

Fixed version: https://jsfiddle.net/xock2ztw/1/

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why I used  the img tag instead of p. Appreciate the help!

Comment: There is an issue with this solution: clicking the buttons in that fiddle hides all elements, always.

Answer (score 0):

Two issues:

- The `$img` selector is not correct. It should be `#people>p` instead `#people img`.
- The variable `p` is not defined. Define it as `var p = this`

Corrected [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1pxp3j9t/5/).

Or this snippet:

```js
$(function() {
    var $imgs = $("#people>p");
    var $buttons = $("#buttons");
    var qualities = {};

    $imgs.each(function() {
    var p = this;
        var properties = $(this).data("qualities");

        if (properties) {
            properties.split(",").forEach(function(quality) {
                if (qualities[quality] == null) {
                    qualities[quality] = [];
                }
                qualities[quality].push(p);
            });
        }
    });

//This button appears.
    $("<button/>", {
        text: "All",
        class: "on",
        click: function() {
            $(this).addClass("on").siblings().removeClass("on");
            $imgs.show();
        }
    }).appendTo($buttons);

//These buttons do not appear.
//There is supposed to generate a button for every different kind of tag.
    $.each(qualities, function(quality) {
        $("<button/>", {
            text: quality + " (" + qualities[quality].length + ")",
            click: function() {
                $(this).addClass("on").siblings().removeClass("on");
                $imgs.hide().filter(qualities[quality]).show();
            }
        }).appendTo($buttons);
    });

});
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

p {
    text-align: center;

    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

    display: inline-block;

    border: solid;
    width: 80px;

    margin: 30px;

    background-color: beige;
}

#people {
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;

    width: 300px;
    background-color: #C3A780;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="buttons"></div>
<div id="people">
<!-- Tags: Fast, Strong, Attractive, Ugly, Weak -->
  <p data-qualities="Fast, Strong, Attractive">Matthew</p>
  <p data-qualities="Ugly"> John</p>
  <p data-qualities="Weak, Ugly"> Jordan</p>
  <p data-qualities="Weak"> Seth</p>
  <p data-qualities="Strong"> Sam</p>
  <p data-qualities="Attractive, Fast">Tejas</p>
  <p data-qualities="Fast, Strong"> Buddy</p>
  <p data-qualities="Ugly, Weak, Strong, Fast"> Jason</p>
</div>
```